# Are (electronic) CAD software related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering whether questions related to PCB CAD software (such as EAGLE) are on-topic. Questions could relate to best practices, BOM generation, proper CAM export, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. According to our <strike>faq</strike> [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic):

> We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

Yours is *a specific electronics design problem*.

Comment: The question I have in mind relates to the specific problem of BOM generation with Eagle, actually. So it's more of a meta electronics design problem that's rather specific to Eagle. My feeling is that this is somewhat off-topic, but seeing that BOM export from Eagle is both widely need and badly implemented, I was thinking it may still make sense to ask.

Comment: @abey no, that doesn't matter. If you're doing something useful for an EE, it's on topic here. At least that's a good rule of thumb.