# Are questions about Solidworks Electrical welcome here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

If I have a question about features of [Solidworks Electrical](https://www.solidworks.com/category/electrical-design), specifically about it's features to draw schematics for power electronics, would they be welcome here?

A possible alternative would be Engineering.SE, but I think it could just as well work here. Just that the [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) isn't explicit about it, so I better ask here first.

Update:
First [solidworks-electrical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks-electrical) question posted [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/368848/53015). Don't hesitate to let me know if I screwed up.

Comment: It probably depends. Have a look at well received altium, eagle etc. questions and if yours is similar it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Post it where you think it would likely be answered if its on topic at both sites. If your the first one then you might be the only one and a different web resource might be more appropriate (wherever the solidworks guys hang out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the line is between how to do 'something' with the software (in-topic) and how to 'use' the software or how it works (off-topic).

Think about it: it should be about engineering, not software support. In that case I think it's fine.

Comment: I'll second this.  Give it a try, @Mast.  (Having said that, [here's an example of a software question with a too superficial scope for EE.SE](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6458/7036).)